# Relationship between composite key and foreign key EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have 2 class that I want to make relationship between it.  the flowing classes:

```
    public class LecturGroup
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public Group Group { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public int LectureId { get; set; }
        public Lecture Lecture { get; set; }

        public IList<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    }
    public class Choice
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public int LecturGroupId { get; set; }
        public LecturGroup LecturGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

To reference 3 composite keys in `LecturGroup` to `LecturGroupId` in `Choice` class I used Fluent API like below:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Choice>().HasKey(s => new { s.StudentId, s.LecturGroupId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<LecturGroup>().HasKey(s => new { s.GroupId, s.TeacherId, s.LectureId });
```

But the created database is look confusing:
[image]

I just want make relationship between 3 composite keys (`GroupId`,`TeacherId`,`LectureId`) that there are foreign key at same time with just one of the another composite key (`LecturGroupId`).
How to Approach it?

Comment: Can you describe in detail how many tables you have and the relationship between them?

Comment: @Yinqiu: I uploded the imge of database in this site  https://imgur.com/K0V8WXA